# Get image url inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```
<li>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-imgs">
            <img src="https://xxxx.png">
        </div>
        <div class="product-desc product-desc-top">
            <h3>Kitten 1</h3>
            <p class="title-desc">This is kitten kitten kitten kitten kitten kitten</p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-desc product-desc-bottom">
            <h4>$ 999</h4>
            <p class="count-buyers">1 buyer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have a lot of `<li>`, and the condition that I wanted is something like this:

If I click on the `<li>` I want to get the img url. Also I wanted to get h3, p, h4, p content.

Is it possible handle this condition using jQuery?

thanks

Comment: In it's current state your question makes no sense (to me). Please try to re-word it if possible as I can't even begin to understand it enough to edit it.

Comment: Yes, totally possible. Post what you've tried so far..

Comment: @JosiahSouth Sorry, my English skill is not good enough. :)

Our friends Binhvi & cherhan got the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it:

// get image url and tags clone.

```
 $(function() {
           $("li").click(function(){
                var imgUrl = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
                var h3 = $(this).find("h3").clone();
                var h4 = $(this).find("h4").clone();
                var title_desc = $(this).find(".title-desc").clone();
                var count_buyers = $(this).find(".count-buyers").clone();
            })
        });
```

// get image url and text on tags.

```
$(function() {
           $("li").click(function(){
                var imgUrl = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
                var h3 = $(this).find("h3").text();
                var h4 = $(this).find("h4").text();
                var title_desc = $(this).find(".title-desc").text();
                var count_buyers = $(this).find(".count-buyers").text();
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
    $('li').click(function()
    {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
var url = $(img).attr('src');        
var h3 = $(this).find('h3').html();
    });
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WZL7J/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li div:first-child div img').attr('src');

var value = $('li div:nth-child(2) div h3').html();

var value2 = $('li div:nth-child(2) div h4').html();
```

And so on.

Comment: please add a comment for the -1

Comment: Ah! I understand the question now. This should not be -1. +1-ing.